# How to get an xDB contact from Shared Session when I only know the identifier?

Tags: xdb

I have a Sitecore 8.1-3 instance.  In my custom code I am trying to write a single method that will get me a Contact instance when all I know is the identifier (email address in this system).  This method could be used in the code behind for a page request for the current logged in user on my site.  Or it could be used by a web service call when all that is passed is the identifier.  Or it could be used on an admin page where an admin is trying to get the information from a contact that is not the current logged in user (admin).

My code is below.  For the most part it works fine.  However if the user changes their identifier (email address) during a session then it fails.  There are two reasons for this.  First we are using web service calls to get all of the user information (dumb architectural decision, but it is what it is).  So because we are using web service calls we do not have access to `Tracker.Current.Contact`.  The second reason for this is that if the user changes their identifier during a session, that change is only in Shared Session. It has not been persisted to mongo yet.  So the part of my code that tries to load the contact from the repository (just to get the Contact Id) fails.  It can't find the contact in the repository using the new identifier.  What I really need is some way to load the contact from Shared Session using only the identifier.  But that doesn't seem to exist.  I can't seem to find a way around this.  I guess I could modify my web service call to somehow include the contact ID, but I don't have access to the developer that built all of that.  I am trying to find a different way around this issue.

```
    private Contact GetXdbContact(string identifier)
    {
        if (Tracker.Current != null && Tracker.Current.Contact != null && Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.Identifier == identifier)
        {
            //This is the current user
            return Tracker.Current.Contact;
        }

        //There is no Tracker.Current.Contact, so this must be running in some non-user context
        var repository = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepositoryBase;
        var sessionManager =
            Factory.CreateObject("tracking/sharedSessionState/manager", true) as SharedSessionStateManager;
        var dbContact = repository.LoadContactReadOnly(identifier);
        if (dbContact != null)
        {
            //Now we have the Contact Id.  Use that Id to actually get the contact from shared session
            var contactId = dbContact.ContactId;
            var sessionContact = sessionManager.LoadContactReadonly(contactId);
            if (sessionContact != null)
            {
                return sessionContact;
            }
            return dbContact;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us how you change a user's identifier mid-session? If you're using `.Identify(newEmail)`, and the contact is not a robot (see `Contact.System.Classification`), then the contact should be flushed to the collection database with its new identifier during `.Identify()`.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: But I can't call `.Identify(newEmail)` because this change is being made in a web service call.  And the web service call is in a different session. `Tracker.Current.Session.Identify` won't work from within a web service call - right?

Comment: Could you please update your question to include the code that changes the identifier of the user in a web service call?